# In microsoft word, while typing the text in a table, if the text is long, how can it autmatically go to next row?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have to type long texts in table rows. I want the text to automatically go to next row of the table instead of going into a new row in the same column.

For example, I want my rows to be like the ones under the activity heading instead of the row "Revise some conversions with the students that will be used in Ex7f  just testing  just testing just testing just testing.

[image]

Comment: It would require programming in VBA (or alternative), and even that would not necessarily be easy. But it is not obvious why you need to split the text up in this way - what is the objective?

Comment: It is the format of the lesson plan. Rows have been inserted and we have to fill it up (by copy/pasting from syllabus pdf file). Everytime the space on one row ends, i have to copy/paste the next set of words to new row. This process is very time consuming.

Comment: That's unfortunate if you are not in a position to get the layout changed or modify it yourself. If the text absolutely has to go into that table, the best I can suggest is that you copy one of your texts into a new blank document and record a macro that inserts paragraph marks at the end of each line, converts the resulting text to a table, select the cells (not the whole table) , copies it to the destination, and fixes the destination formatting. But I think it would be quite difficult to get that right enough to save you time, and it assumes you are in a position to record/use macros.